# Json - Prepare for segue to Details View

Tags: ios, json, swift, detailsview

I'm trying coding the View with the details elements from the Json. However the compiler crash with the prepare for segue.

```
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!

let yourJsonFormat: String = "JSONFile" // set text JSONFile : json data from file
                                        // set text JSONUrl : json data from web url

var arrDict :NSMutableArray=[]
```

// @IBOutlet weak var eventCalendar: UITableView!

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

    if yourJsonFormat == "JSONFile" {
        jsonParsingFromFile()
    } else {
        jsonParsingFromURL()
    }
}


func jsonParsingFromURL () {

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://theappguruz.in//Apps/iOS/Temp/json.php")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
        self.startParsing(data!)
    }
}


func jsonParsingFromFile()
{
    let path: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("days", ofType: "json")!
    let data : NSData = try! NSData(contentsOfFile: path as String, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMapped)

    self.startParsing(data)
}

func startParsing(data :NSData)
{
    let dict: NSDictionary!=(try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary

    for var i = 0 ; i < (dict.valueForKey("objects") as! NSArray).count ; i++ {
        arrDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("objects") as! NSArray) .objectAtIndex(i))
    }
}
```

//   eventCalendar .reloadData()

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return arrDict.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    let strName : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("name") as! NSString
    let strSubtitle : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("subtitle") as! NSString
    let strLocation : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("location") as! NSString
    let strStart : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("start") as! NSString

    if let strImage = arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("image") as? String {

        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:strImage )!) {
            cell.lbImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }

    cell.lbName.text=strName as String
    cell.lbSubtitle.text=strSubtitle as String
    cell.lbStart.text=strStart as String
    cell.lbLocation.text=strLocation as String

    return cell as TableViewCell
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var detailView = segue.destinationViewController as! EventDetail

    if segue.identifier == EventDetail.identifier() {

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let selectedRow = indexPath.row
            let selected = self.arrDict[selectedRow]
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! EventDetail
            vc.ARRDICT = selected as! NSMutableArray
        }
    }
}
```

And error message is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: Please add complete code. For example the structure for `arrDict`. Why not send the info in sender?

Comment: I put the code... Why do you think the sender is better? Thank You.

Comment: Have you added 'showEventDetail' segue identifier in storyboard? If no, open storyboard, find your segue and identify it with 'showEventDetail' id.

Comment: Yes, I added showEventDetail in storyBoard. And error message is: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: Most likely `arrDict` is empty. Show the code where it's declared and populated. — and stop using `valueForKey` in this environment.

Comment: @vadian Could you help me with more details?

Comment: Regarding `valueForKey`: It's a KVC method with a special behavior. To get a value from a dictionary key use `objectForKey` or key subscripting. And you can cast to `String` directly. Regarding the `out of bounds` error: Once again, *Show the code where `arrDict` is declared and populated*

Comment: I update the code above. Do you have some suggestion without valueForKey?

Comment: The code is very confusing. It seems that the second part of the `startParsing` function actually belongs to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and you pasted three times exactly the same `for` loop.

Comment: @vadian Now I put the complete code...

Comment: I suppose that the error is in this line `self.arrDict[selectedRow]`. The error is clear, `self.arrDict` is empty and you is trying to pass a index to empty array. is obviously, the question is why `arrDict` is empty. You need put logs in all the process and check in what part occur that

Answer (score 0):

only for test you should remove the automatic segue in the storyboard and add a manual segue (type show), using identifier and call `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourIdentifier", sender: sender)` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` this method have `indexPath` use this indexpath for get the position in array and try to send that object in that position as sender parameter. And get it in the `prepareForSegue`.

Please change your `startParsing` loop to.

```
let arrayObjects = dict.valueForKey("objects") as! NSArray
for eachDict in arrayObjects {
  let dict = eachDict as! NSDictionary
  arrDict.addObject(dict)
}
```

for better `level of complexity`